# Access derive class from a base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to access `derive class` from a `base class pointer`, but my code is not working and I am not getting what is wrong

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{

public:
    int n1;
    void display()
    {
        cout << "\nBase number is: " << n1 << endl;
    }
};
class derive : public base
{
public:
    int n2;
    void display()
    {
        cout << "\nBase number is: " << n1 << endl;
        cout << "\nDerived number is: " << n2 << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base b;
    base *bptr; //base pointer
    bptr = &b;     
    bptr->n1 = 44; //access base class via base pointer
    bptr->display();
    derive d;
    cout << "\n";
    bptr = &d;     
    bptr->n2 = 66; //access derive class via base pointer //here it is showing that 'base class has no member n2'
    bptr->display();
}
```

Comment: `base *bptr;` is a pointer to `base` - it may or may not point to an object of type `derive`. You need to explicitly downcast to a pointer of `derive` (and check that you actually have such an object) in order to access any of its members

Comment: Write a virtual function.

Comment: Declare `base::display()` as `virtual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access derived class' members using a base pointer, if you are sure that `bptr` is indeed pointing to a `derive` instance, you could cast it to a pointer to `derive` and use it

```
auto dptr = static_cast<derive*>(bptr);
dptr->n2 = 66;
```

EDIT: There is a bigger problem in your code, `display` is not virtual in base class, hence the class `derive` is not actually polymorphic.

`static_cast` will complain at compile time itself, if it sees that there is no conversion from `base*` to `derived*` It won't prevent though from doing something as below

```
base b;
base *bptr; //base pointer
bptr = &b;     
bptr->n1 = 44; //access base class via base pointer
bptr->display();
derive d;
cout << "\n";
//bptr = &d;   //bptr is still pointing to a base instance.

auto dptr = static_cast<derive*>(bptr);
dptr->n2 = 66;
```

A better way is to use `dynamic_cast` and test if the conversion was actually successful

```
auto dptr = dynamic_cast<derive>(bptr);
if (dptr)
   dptr->n2 - 66; // indeed bptr holds a derive instance
```